# how to append text to file in specific location in python3?

Tags: python, file-writing

i'm trying to append text to file in specific location.
i want to create program which takes input from user(name, image, id) and adds them to this file

```
names = []
images = []
id = 0
url = ['https://somewebsiteUsingId10.com',
       'https://somewebsiteUsingId20.com']
if id == 5:
    names.append("Testing Names")
    images.append("Testing Images")
elif id == 0:
    names.append("Testing one names")
    images.append("Testing one Images")
```

I want modified file to be like this:

```
names = []
images = []
id = 0
url = ['https://somewebsiteUsingId20.com',
       'https://somewebsiteUsingId10.com',
       'https://somewebsiteUsingId50.com']
if id == 5:
    names.append("Testing Names")
    images.append("Testing Images")
elif id == 0:
    names.append("Testing one names")
    images.append("Testing one Images")
elif id == 50:
    names.append("User input")
    images.append("User Input")
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have already shown the code you want here, why don't you just use it?

Comment: i want to create external program. which takes input (images,id,names) and puts them there. so i don't have to add by hand. for example if i use that program 5 times, i want to add 5 more "elifs with that info" and add in "url" too. i hope i explained well <3

Comment: Do you want to write a program that modifies itself?

Comment: i want to create other program, which opens this file. and modifies it.

Comment: Don't try to modify the code, put the data separately in some file and use it as needed in your code.

Comment: i'm stuck on that

Comment: like, 
names = input()
images = input()
id = input()

with open("thisFile.py", "a") as f:
    f.write() // and i want to pass in names, id, image. and everytime i use this program i want to add those. is that possible?, i want these to be in different program.

Comment: guys no idea? what do you think? <3

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, a good course of action is to put the variable data in a *configuration file*.

On start-up, your program reads the configuration file and processes it.

Another program can update the configuration file.

Python has the `json` module in its standard library. This supports lists and dicts, so it is a good match for Python data structures.

Say you write a file `urls.json`, looking like this:

```
[
    "https://somewebsiteUsingId20.com",
    "https://somewebsiteUsingId10.com",
    "https://somewebsiteUsingId50.com"
]
```

In your program you can then do:

```
import json

with open("urls.json") as f:
    urls = json.load(f)
```

The variable `urls` now points to a list containing the aforementioned URLs.

Writing the config data goes about the same:

```
urls = [
    "https://www.parrot.org",
    "https://www.ministryofsillywalks.org",
    "https://www.cheese.net",
]

with open("newurls.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(urls, f, indent=4)
```

The file `newurls.json` now contains:

```
[
    "https://www.parrot.org",
    "https://www.ministryofsillywalks.org",
    "https://www.cheese.net"
]
```

Note that JSON is pretty flexible, you are not limited to strings:

```
import datetime

config = {
    'directories': ["https://www.parrot.org", "https://www.ministryofsillywalks.org"],
    'saved': str(datetime.datetime.now()),
    'count': 12
}

with open("configuration.json", "w") as cf:
    json.dump(config, cf, indent=4)
```

This would result in something like:

```
{
    "directories": [
        "https://www.parrot.org",
        "https://www.ministryofsillywalks.org"
    ],
    "saved": "2022-02-07 21:21:14.787420",
    "count": 12
}
```

(You'd get another date/time, of course.)

The only major downside to JSON files is that they don't allow comments. If you *need* comments, use another format like the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module.

Note that there are other methods like `shelve` and `read`&`eval` but those have potential safety issues.

Comment: hey, so i understand what you said, but i couldn't write that. can you please show me code example? <3

Comment: @Varsima See updated answer. Stackoverflow went off-line just as I was typing the examples yesterday. :-(